# Ask for missing DB data with Alexa

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to do the following with Alexa:

- When a user say: open APP_NAME
- I'm checking the DynamoDB to see if I have the name of the suer
- if not I'd like to ask for the name before I tell what the app can do

I did try to use

```
this.emit(":delegate", "name_add");
```

From the Intent that is triggered when you say "open APP_NAME", this means that in the Hello intent I make a query, check if I have the name, and if not I'd like to trigger another Intent to get the missing data.

But when I use Delegate, the "name_add" intent is not being triggered.

## My questions

When I'm in one intent that relies on data from the DB, and I see that there is data missing, how should I go about collecting this missing data? Mind you, once this data is in the DB I won't ask the user about it. So it is a one time thing.

Meaning I know how to take advantage of slots, when you ask for example from where are you flying to where. Because this is something that Alexa will ask each time. But what when you need to do this one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you cannot delegate to a new intent. [Read about Dialog Directives here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#delegate).

> Note that you cannot change intents when returning a Dialog directive, so the intent name and set of slots must match the intent sent to your skill.

So you are going to have to restructure your intents.

**Suggested Structure:**
Normally, your `helloIntent` (when the user opens your skill 'naked': `"Alexa, open mySkill."` instead of 'with clothing': `"Alexa, open mySkill and do something"`), this is when you want to direct the user into saying what to do that will trigger your main intents.

So the `helloIntent` will simply respond with: `"Hello, welcome to mySkill, you can say things like, do something, or, do something else"`

The user then says one of those things, which is an utterance of your other intents, therefore triggering one of those intents, lets call one: `"checkDatabase"`.

Now that you are inside of `"checkDatabase"` intent, you can have a required slot called `name`. This is when you can check the DB for a user's name and fill the slot yourself, or delegate back to Alexa to elicit `name`.

**Things to know:**
1) Delegate only works with required slots of the intent. You are *delegating* to Alexa to figure out what slots are needed to be filled and which to elicit first. She figures this out based on the order of the required slots you have set up for the intent in the Console.

2) `this.emit(':delegate', updatedIntent);` (using the Alexa SDK) needs the second parameter `updatedIntent` to be an object of the full intent information which includes the name, slots and confirmationStatus ([see Intent Object here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-types-reference.html#intent-object)). If you fill slots yourself, this is how you return the 'updated' intent information.

3) For more control in which slots to elicit and with a specific message, use [ElicitSlot Directive](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html#elicitslot). 
Which in the Alexa SDK is: `this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech, updatedIntent)` [Read about that here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#elicit-slot-directive).
(ElicitSlot must be used to elicit unrequired slots)

Comment: Right but in his case I'd need a Name slot in each intent because the user can ask any question in a random order - right? And my perplexity is that it seams that there is o way to have one place that handle the name "asking" to have one code that deals with that, right?

Comment: I see. Yes, that is how I would do it. Put a name slot and elicit question for that slot in each intent. Good news is, that's all you would need to do, because after you fill the slot in one intent, either by asking for it or getting from DB, save it in sessionAttributes as well. This way you only need to check once in Lambda if you know the name, no matter which intent they trigger. Each intent just needs to have the name slot prepared in the Console.

Comment: Here's one idea for a work-around. Create a single intent with utterance "My name is {name}". And if the user ever triggers any intent and you don't have the name yet, send them a ':tell' message asking them to say that specific utterance and include their name. Something like: "Please say, my name is, then give your name." The user then says that full utterance which triggers your name_get intent and fills the name slot there. You can save both their original_intent and their name in sessionAttributes,

Comment: Personally though, I'd go with a name slot in every intent, since the work-around relies too much on the user following exact directions, and doesn't feel as natural as just asking "What is your name?" from within any intent.

Comment: Interesting, I think I'm getting it. So a slot can be filled by Alexa when "she" detects that the name slot is empty, or I can programmatically fill the content of the name slot. Right?

Comment: That's right. You tell Alexa to detect and ask for empty *required* slots by telling her to "Delegate". Or you tell Alexa to ask for any specific slot by telling her to "ElicitSlot". And at any point you can programmatically  fill (or empty) slots yourself before returning them in "updatedIntent".